# OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication IsSuccessful returns false how do I to determine the reason?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, dotnetopenauth

I'm using DotNetOpenAuth with a MVC 4 application. All the sudden Google auth is failing (MS is working). The stock code does this:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
{
    var result = OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication(Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
    if (!result.IsSuccessful)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("ExternalLoginFailure");
    }
```

I know that `result.IsSuccessful` is false, but how do I get the reason? `result.Error` is null.

I also looked at [this page](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/developers/help/loggingdebugging-dotnetopenauth-with-log4net/) to use log4net. I do get a log on the local dev box but not when I deploy it to a remote server.

log4net webconfig:

```
<log4net>
    <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="RelyingParty.log" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
      <maximumFileSize value="100KB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date (GMT%date{%z}) [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <!-- Setup the root category, add the appenders and set the default level -->
    <root>
      <level value="INFO" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
    </root>
    <!-- Specify the level for some specific categories -->
    <logger name="DotNetOpenAuth">
      <level value="ALL" />
    </logger>
  </log4net>
```

**Edit** I also tried log4net to a sql db but it still didn't log anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally figured this out. The actual error message I was getting:

```
Protocol error: This message has a timestamp of 10/23/2012 12:19:33 PM, 
which is beyond the allowable clock skew for in the future.
```

Turns out after a server crash the timezone didn't get set correctly. This caused the validation/token to fail from google's end.

The `AdoNetAppender` was "not working" because `bufferSize` was set to 100. After setting it to 1 it started getting logs. Here is the adonetappender I'm using

```
  <log4net>
        <appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
      <bufferSize value="1" />
      <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      <connectionStringName value="CONNECTIONSTRINGNAME" />
      <commandText value="INSERT INTO Log4Net ([Date],[Thread],[Level],[Logger],[Message],[Exception]) VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, @logger, @message, @exception)" />
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@log_date" />
        <dbType value="DateTime" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@thread" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="255" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%thread" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@log_level" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="50" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%level" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@logger" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="255" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%logger" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@message" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="4000" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%message" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@exception" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="2000" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout" />
      </parameter>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="Debug" />
      <appender-ref ref="AdoNetAppender" />
    </root>
    <logger name="DotNetOpenAuth">
      <level value="ALL" />
    </logger>
  </log4net>
```

You should set the `bufferSize` back to 100 when you get your issue worked out.

Comment: I am having the same issue but I have not used log4net . So how can I solve this issue?

Comment: umm.. install log4net? log4net is how DotNetOpenAuth logs any issues it has. then either ask a question on SO or resolve the issue from the logs