# Google+ Sign In Or DotnetOpenAuth OAuth2.0

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-plus, dotnetopenauth

Recently I have started experiencing the same problem as mentioned in [AuthenticationResult.IsSuccessful started returning false for google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21370874/authenticationresult-issuccessful-started-returning-false-for-google).

I am confused between choosing Google+ Sign In or using DotnetOpenAuth's OAuth2.0 implementation.

Right now I am using DotnetOpenAuth with ASP.NET simple membership provider as seen in Internet Application template in MVC4.